# I just don't understand how docker works

Tags: docker, cloud, virtual-machine

I've read some articles about
VM(vmware, virtualbox..) vs docker.
But I just can't understand what is going on..

There's an example of creating your own docker image.
They start with pulling ubuntu images from docker hub.
..install some stuffs in there...
django for example
and make all of it as an docker image.

Then, If you have docker installed in mac.

running that image should be like
(HOST) MAC > docker > ubuntu VM > django?
isn't it??

They say docker make it possible to run django like
MAC > docker > django image
But when you are making the image you starts with ubuntu..
and django must be ubuntu based django..

Where did I missed the point??

and some docker images like mysql ..
what is the base os of the that running mysql?
Is it possible to run that same docker image
in ubuntu / in centos / together??
how?

Answer (score 0):

Don't see the "from  Ubuntu" like a VM with Ubuntu, but just as the libs from Ubuntu to run the rest of the Docker image. Each container does not load an entire OS, but use its host ressources.
And see docker as a Cloud : you will have a process (a container) running something and listening on a specific port.

Comment: hmm......  then how can docker run [apps that is based on ubuntu libs] on centos?

Comment: Because the Linux kernel of both Ubuntu and centos have the nessary libs to run containers.